# LambdaExpression gets incorrect DeclaringType for overriden property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have following classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string FooProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override string FooProperty { get => base.FooProperty; set => base.FooProperty = value; }
}
```

I define a lambda expression:

```
Expression<Func<Bar, string>> expression = (Bar b) => b.FooProperty;
```

When I check the DeclaringType of the MemberExpression I get type `Foo` and not `Bar` like I expected. Why is this?

```
var type = (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.DeclaringType;   // returns Foo type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a tricky one. Technically `Bar` *is* declaring a property, and that property is called `FooProperty`.  We can see this by getting the `Type` of `Bar`, getting it's `FooProperty` info and printing *its* declaring type.

```
var prop = typeof(Bar).GetProperty("FooProperty");
Console.WriteLine(prop.DeclaringType);
```

*That* will print out `Bar`, not `Foo`.  So `Bar` *is* declaring a property, but, the reason the code you showed results in `Foo` is that both `Foo` and `Bar` declare a property called `FooProperty`, but on the call site it's not actually calling `Bar.FooProperty`, it's calling out to the base type's version and letting virtual dispatch handle ensuring that *the property that `Bar` declared* is the one that actually executes, of the two declared properties.  This means that the declaring type *of the property that is called* (which is what you're computing when you get the member info from the expression, rather than from navigating the type, as I did above) is `Foo`, even though both types have declared a property called `FooProperty`.

Comment: Thank you! What I really want to achieve is to check custom attributes on the property that I have specifically only declared on `Bar.FooProperty`. Guess I have to get the `PropertyInfo` with the type from the lambda expression's parameter.

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson Keep in mind that if the object that is actually passed in is a derived type of `Bar` that has attributes with different values than what `Bar` has for the declaration of that method then you won't be seeing the attribute for the version that actually executes.  (You could mark `Bar`'s declaration as `sealed` if you wanted to prevent this as a possibility.)

Comment: Good point. I'm only using the expressions as configuration this time so I won't actually compile and invoke them.

Comment: As noted in the comments on my now-deleted answer, I'm really surprised that `prop.DeclaringType` returns `Bar` here rather than `Foo`. I don't regard this as declaring a new method, but overriding an existing method. The C# spec says this: "Whereas a virtual method declaration *introduces* a new method, an override method declaration *specializes* an existing inherited virtual method by providing a new implementation of that method." I guess I can't argue that it's declaring something though, given that it's a *method-declaration*. Tricky stuff.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a `MethodInfo.OverriddenMember` and maybe `MethodInfo.OriginalDeclaringType` or something similar to allow you to find out which member is being overridden. (Just like there's `ReflectedType` to find out which type you were asking on.) Lots of different things that *could* be useful...

Comment: @JonSkeet My guess is this is a case of .NET and C# having different definitions for the same word.  As per the C# specs I wouldn't be surprised if it defined overriding a member to not be declaring a new member, but apparently .NET *does* define "declaring a member" to include overridden members.  I haven't checked the C# specs to confirm if they actually differ though.

Comment: @Servy: I guess I'd go with "declaring a member" but not "declaring a **new** member" (emphasis mine). Fiddly semantics like this are hard :( Interesting to see that the expression tree accurately represents the binding in the IL rather than what you'd get via "obvious" reflection though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just skimming the C# 5 specs, I've seen this quote, "For virtual methods and indexers defined in classes, the parameter list is picked from the first
declaration or override of the function member found when starting with the static type of the
receiver, and searching through its base classes." (section 12.6.2.2) which implies that overriding a member isn't declaring it (given the non-inclusive or.  Similar wording is used in several places.

Comment: But then later on it says, "To locate the particular
method invoked by a method invocation, start with the type indicated by the method invocation and
proceed up the inheritance chain until at least one applicable, accessible, non-override method declaration
is found." (section 12.7.6.2).  Referring to non-override declarations implies that there is such a thing as an overridden method declaration (more skimming shows that this term is also used in several places).  So given all of this I can only say that the term appears to have an inconsistent definition in the C# specs.

Comment: @JonSkeet The most on-point quote I've found yet is, "Similarly, a
method declaration with the override modifier shall not have any type-parameter-constraints-clauses [...]" (section 15.6.1)  This pretty clearly states that overriding a method is itself a method declaration.

Comment: @Servy: Yup, I'd say it's a method declaration, but not that it declares a new method. I'd say it declares a new implementation of an existing method. I may see if we can tighten it up in a later version...